# C++ why does empty set::emplace() inserts an element into a set of pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, set, move-semantics

Consider the following code:

```
struct A{};

int main()
{
    std::set<A*> aset;
    aset.emplace();
    std::cout << aset.size() << std::endl;   //prints "1"
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e72bf53a94a1efaf)

Why does the empty `emplace()` adds an element to the set of pointers?

Comment: Same reason it'd add an element if the elements weren't pointers. Why would you expect otherwise? (Note that it doesn't construct a pointed-to object.)

Comment: @user2357112: but using `std::set<A> aset;` gives a compile-time error. It's not quite the same imo.

Comment: @davidhigh It fails to compile because you have not defined a comparison operator for `A`, not because of your call to `emplace`. (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51431ffd8e2b2a1c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace) will:

> [Insert] a new element into the container by constructing it in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.

The container was previously empty, so you're definitely going to insert a new element. Zero arguments is a valid constructor for `A*`, so the code compiles and you end up with a `set` with one, value-initialized pointer to `A`.